# Помогите выбрать среду разработки приложения для отображения/мониторинга данных из нескольких серверов

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, xml

Есть три сервера с портами которые служат для коммуникации между клиентом и оператором сотовой сети и взаимодействуют через передатчики. Нужно разработать программу (может framework) для отображения/мониторинга состояния загруженности портов.

Есть статистика и данные из сервера - которые постоянно обновляются 24/7 - на 5-ти разных страницах и отображаться могут в `html`/`xml`/`json`.

Подскажите, в какой среде разработки можно собрать все эти данные из этих 5 страниц в одну программу для отображения/мониторинга общей статистики по серверам с портами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону готовых решений для мониторинга вроде Zabbix или Graphite. Вам нужно будет только  написать небольшую программу (хотя бы на Java, хотя можно и что-то более легковесное вроде Python), которая будет опрашивать сервера, забирать json и перекладывать его в систему мониторинга.  А все остальное - дашборды, хранение истории, красивые графички, запросы и агрегация - у вас будет из коробки.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!